# Elasticsearch bool query with filter doesn't work on field with "-"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple document in my index per customer:

```
{"customer":"m-test-service", "customer_id":"x55sg" "book":"f","date"....}
{"customer":"m-test-service", "customer_id":"x55sg" "book":"g","date"....}
{"customer":"x12", "customer_id":"dhb5" "book":"e","date"....}
{"customer":"x12", "customer_id":"dhb5" "book":"d","date"....}
```

I want to retrieve all the documents that has both customer and customer_id set to some two specific values like the following SQL query : `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CUSTOMER='XXX' AND CUSTOMER_ID="YYYY"`.

I have been using the following query :

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter" : [
          {"term" : {"customer" : "x12"} },
          {"term" : {"customer_id" : "dhb5"}}
        ]
    
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to query a customer that has `"-"` in its string I don't get any documents. I tried to run the previous query mentioned with the following values:

```
"customer":"m-test-service", "customer_id":"x55sg"
```

and I didn't get results.

When I remove the `'-'` char from the customer field I got results including the documents of m-test-service.

Why is this char problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Term query returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.**

If you want to search for `"customer":"m-test-service"`, then try using `customer.keyword` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter" : [
          {"term" : {"customer.keyword" : "m-test-service"} },
          {"term" : {"customer_id" : "x55sg"}}
        ]
    
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `customer` field in your mapping is `text` which is using the `standard` analyzer while breaks the text, you should use `.keyword` field if its dynamically generated otherwise using [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) you should add it and query it.

Comment: Thanks, indeed this was the case